# About the correctnes of two inequaliies with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am asking if there is an error in the following inequalities with exponential function:

Assuming that $x≥a+1$ and $x>b$ where $a,b>1$

**Method 1**:

$$x^{x-1}≥x^{a+1-1}= x^{a}> b^{a}$$

**Method 2**:

The function $x→x^{x-1}$ is strictly increasing, then $x≥a+1$ imply $$x^{x-1}≥(a+1)^{a+1-1}= (a+1)^{a}> a^{a}> b^{a}$$
if $a>b$

Comment: There are not mistakes but you can apply the method 1 even if $a\le b$.

Comment: Method 2 also has the disadvantage that you need to also prove that $x\mapsto x^{x-1}$ is strictly increasing. Just stating it is not sufficient. Method 1 relies only on the theorems (presumably already shown) that if $x > 1$ and $r \ge s \ge 0$, then $x^r \ge x^s$, and if $x  > y$ and $r > 0$ then $x^r > y^r$.